# Can we see or edit 'job bookmark' info in AWS glue or where it get stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I created a glue job and enabled the job bookmark, want to see the metadata stored by glue to keep track of processed files.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I asked myself the same question and the documentation does not mention it.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use `aws glue get-job-bookmark --job-name <job_name>` to get the content of the bookmark. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-job-bookmark.html for detail.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately AWS Glue job bookmarking details are not available for customers. As far as I know it is based on the job name, source file name and `transformationContext` strings passed to DynamicFrame's methods like `getSinkWithFormat()`, `applyMapping()`, `getCatalogSource()`.

Besides that `Job.init()` and `Job.commit()` must be called at the beginning and end of a script respectively to make bookmarking working.